# How can I stop my laptop from shutting down unexpectedly?

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, overheating

My laptop has shut down several times while using youtube after short periods of time. I can feel heat coming from the bottom. Just before it shuts off it displays a black screen with some text on it, lasting about a second.

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04. I have tried running it on both Adobe Flash player as well as HTML5. The only proprietary driver it has is for the WiFi card. Laptop is running dual boot with Windows Vista. Don't know my way around Linux too well, so simple explanations would be much appreciated.

system specifications (in case they might be helpful in diagnosis):

- Dell Inspiron 1525 (from 2008-09)
- Intel Celeron 2.00 GHz
- 2GB memory
- 32 bit
- 110-ish GB hdd
- graphics card is "mobile Intel 965 express chipset family"

think i got what you were talking about entered

```
grep -iE "(emergency|temperature)" /var/log/syslog
```

got

```
Jun 20 01:19:24 ubuntu kernel: [ 3617.333801] Critical temperature reached (99 C), shutting down.
Jun 20 01:34:21 ubuntu kernel: [  867.196196] Critical temperature reached (99 C), shutting down.
Jun 20 02:43:52 ubuntu kernel: [ 1708.282274] Critical temperature reached (99 C), shutting down.
```

those are the three times it over heated -- entirety of it:

```
yaser@ubuntu:~$ grep -iE "(emergency|temperature)" /var/log/syslog
Jun 20 01:05:19 ubuntu kernel: [ 2772.442355] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 20 01:05:19 ubuntu kernel: [ 2772.443338] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 20 01:14:22 ubuntu kernel: [ 3314.933437] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 7)
Jun 20 01:14:22 ubuntu kernel: [ 3314.934428] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 20 01:19:22 ubuntu kernel: [ 3614.942666] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 27260)
Jun 20 01:19:22 ubuntu kernel: [ 3614.943649] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 20 01:19:24 ubuntu kernel: [ 3617.333801] Critical temperature reached (99 C), shutting down.
Jun 20 01:20:26 ubuntu kernel: [    0.515893] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 20 01:20:26 ubuntu kernel: [    0.516881] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 20 01:26:10 ubuntu kernel: [  376.280224] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 11)
Jun 20 01:26:10 ubuntu kernel: [  376.281204] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 20 01:34:20 ubuntu kernel: [  866.633368] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 12689)
Jun 20 01:34:20 ubuntu kernel: [  866.634349] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 20 01:34:21 ubuntu kernel: [  867.196196] Critical temperature reached (99 C), shutting down.
Jun 20 02:41:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 1587.408477] CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jun 20 02:41:51 ubuntu kernel: [ 1587.409462] CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Jun 20 02:43:52 ubuntu kernel: [ 1708.282274] Critical temperature reached (99 C), shutting down.
```

thanks a ton for the help Cleaned fan works smoothly now, couldn't figure out the amd propriety driver though

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What does your system log say about that time? I suspect a kernel emergency shutdown due to high temperatures (inadequate cooling). Look at `/var/log/syslog` and scroll up to the time about it happened or search through the file, e.g. `grep -iE "(emergency|temperature)" /var/log/syslog`. Please include all new information **in** your question by *editing* it.

Comment: Your machine is clearly overheating beyond its limits. This should not happen and really is a hardware issue. That this does not happen on Windows just indicates that it's not working at 100% speed there and may be inhibiting power saving features not present in Ubuntu for your hardware. Clean out the fans and return it for being faulty under warranty claims if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

**As for the hardware part:**

I solved the same problem on the same model (with Windows) recently. You are lucky, in this model it is really easy to clean the cpu cooler. You may only open the small cover of the CPU/RAM, unscrew the cooling system and it's cover and clean the dust from the fins. NOT only the dust from the fan. Think that it is the only way your laptop "breathes" and it is blocked with a "blanket" made of dust! You may also replace the thermal compound. These two together will for sure make things a lot better.

[Videos such this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UMqYV5PHWc) may help you. (you need only the first two minutes of this)

**As for the software part:**

Try the AMD's proprietary driver for the GPU. In my case (other model), it lowered the temperature a lot. Although, maybe things have changed latelly as for the power-saving features of the open source drivers.